# How to perform an Asynchronous Integration in Oracle Integration Cloud (OIC)

Tags: oracle, soap, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, cloud-integration

There's the need to create an asynchronous integration between two systems, using OIC. Let me walk you through this.

So as a first step, a system is calling OIC to an exposed Web Service.
OIC then needs to answer back to this system by saying "SUCCESS", as an acknowledgement.
After retrieving the message, OIC needs to perform 4-5 synchronous calls to another system, as the target.
After all these 4-5 calls are successfully over, OIC is replying back to the Source system, which is exposing another Web Service. This final message is the final response for the integration.

My question is, how can I return the first acknowledgement message and then invoke another internal integration, in order to make the synchronous calls and reply back to the source system, as a callback. Is there the need to use the Process applications?

Mind that SOAP protocol is used for all the service calls.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured how exactly this can happen, you simply need to propagate your message to an asynchronous integration, so that OIC can understand it and should not wait for a response.

Answer (score 0):

simple do the below.

first oic integration should be synchronus , in the same integration call the asychronous service as local integration service . in that way the first sync oic will respond immediately after receiving the request and also it will kick the aysnchornous service.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Create the main integration an asynchronous integration and then invoke other synchronous integrations from inside the main integration. Main integration can't return a response body only accepted code e.g. 202 will be returned.

Client of main integration will get the response status immediately and will not wait for other synchronous integration called from inside main integration as main integration is an asynchronous integration.